# ng-repeat data switch based on click

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, frontend

Hello I am new in angular js

Is it possible ng-repeat data change on click without dom change?

[see Example](http://jsfiddle.net/8s4afddv/)

In this example - When the click on 'names' tab then show names list from 'names' array , same as when the click on 'ids' tab then content replace with ids list

Is it possible manage from controller with same dom element?

```
<div class="select"><span class="active">Names</span> <span>ID</span></div>
<ul ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="testController">
    <li ng-repeat="name in names">{{name.name}}</li>
</ul>

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('testController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.names = [
        {name : 'nameOne'},
        {name : 'nameTwo'},
        {name : 'nameThree'},
        {name : 'nameFour'},
        {name : 'nameFive'}
    ];

       $scope.IDs = [
        {id : 'idOne'},
        {id : 'idTwo'},
        {id : 'idThree'},
        {id : 'idFour'},
        {id : 'idFive'}
    ];    

});
```

Thanks

Comment: can you exaplain what you mean _manage from controller with same dom element_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
<div class="select"><span class="active" ng-click="changeToName()">Names</span> <span ng-click="changeToID()">ID</span></div>
<ul ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="testController">
    <li ng-repeat="name in myRepeat">{{ (name.name || name.id) }}</li>
</ul>
```

in the controller

```
  //default empty - but you could set it to a default like $scope.myRepeat = $scope.names;
  $scope.myRepeat = [];

 $scope.changeToName = function(){
     $scope.myRepeat = $scope.names;
 };

   $scope.changeToID = function(){
     $scope.myRepeat = $scope.IDs;
 };
```

I just placed a different scope variable to the ng-repeat the data between `$scope.myRepeat`, which you can switch the data inside with some click functions. You can default it to having `$scope.names` as it's value, or an empty array, depends how you want it to be used.

**FIDDLE** - http://jsfiddle.net/8s4afddv/2/

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
<div class="select"><span class="active">Names</span> <span>ID</span></div>
<ul ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="testController">
    <li ng-repeat="item in lists()">{{item[prop]}}</li>
</ul>
<button onclick="list = 'id'"> Click to change to ID <button/>

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('testController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.prop = "name";
    $scope.lists = function() {
    var list;
    if ($scope.list === "names") {
        $scope.prop = "name";
        list = [
          {name : 'nameOne'},
          {name : 'nameTwo'},
          {name : 'nameThree'},
          {name : 'nameFour'},
          {name : 'nameFive'}
        ];
      }
    } else if ($scope.list === "id") {
      $scope.prop = "id";
      list = [
        {id : 'idOne'},
        {id : 'idTwo'},
        {id : 'idThree'},
        {id : 'idFour'},
        {id : 'idFive'}
      ];    
    }
    return list;

});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how i'd do it. If i had more time id build the entire thing into its own directive(the buttons on the top part kinda bother me still), but this should get you started (its been a while since i used angular, sorry!)

http://jsfiddle.net/8s4afddv/5/

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('testController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.activeList = [];
    $scope.change = function(t){
     $scope.activeList = $scope[t];
    };

    $scope.names = [
        {name : 'nameOne'},
        {name : 'nameTwo'},
        {name : 'nameThree'},
        {name : 'nameFour'},
        {name : 'nameFive'}
    ];
    $scope.IDs = [
        {id : 'idOne'},
        {id : 'idTwo'},
        {id : 'idThree'},
        {id : 'idFour'},
        {id : 'idFive'}
    ];    


})
.directive('myList', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    template: '<ul><li ng-repeat="name in activeList">{{ (name.name || name.id) }}</li></ul>'
  };
});
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="testController">
<div class="select" ><span class="active" ng-click="change('names')">Names</span> <span ng-click="change('IDs')">ID</span></div>

<my-list>
</my-list>

</div>
```